# Where to get legendary class mods in DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

I can't find any legendary class mods, ever since I've got the Borderland2 DLC. They aren't in the typical spot in UVHM.

Answer (score 1):

Like most legendary loot, Legendary Class Mods have increased chances to show up from certain bosses, and are otherwise extremely rare (they're still very rare from the RIGHT bosses).

[For instance the Siren class mod has these bosses, according to the Borderlands Wikia](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Siren)

> The Legendary Siren is obtained randomly from any suitable loot source but has an increased chance to drop from Vermivorous The Invincible, Pete the Invincible, Voracidous the Invincible and Ancient Dragons of Destruction.

[Just find the item you want in this list](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Legendary) and click the item name to check out the drop targets for farming. And remember not all targets are equally farmable for whatever reason; Hyperious the Invincible for example is ANNOYING and slow to fight, while Voracidous takes a while to spawn and is based on random chance. Happy hunting.